# joins on four tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider a small example i have the below tables where it looks like this

```
Employee(eid(pkey),ename)
supply(sid(pkey),sname,eid(fkey))
supplier(suid(pkey),supname,sid(fkey))
item(iid(pkey),itemname,suid(fkey))
```

help in  sql joins so the output be  below format

i need to display all eids and ename even though they dont have item name related to them

```
eid , ename ,  itemname
```

to get item name

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  I also think sample data and desired results would really help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: `select ... from t1 join t2 on t1.x = t2.y join t3 on ... join t4 on ...`

Comment: i use oracle data base

Comment: If you use oracle, then make an effort and post the results.  Also, visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown no attempt to solve the problem himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using left joins, and starting from employee, even the employees without items will be selected.

```
select 
 e.eid, 
 e.ename,
 i.itemname
from employee e
left join supply s on s.eid = e.eid
left join supplier su on su.sid = s.sid
left join item i on i.suid = su.suid
```

Without the requirement to also select employees without items, it's better to start joining from item:

```
select 
 i.itemname,
 s.supname as suppliername,
 su.sname as supplyname,
 e.eid as empid, 
 e.ename as empname
from item i
left join supplier su on su.suid = i.suid
left join supply s on s.sid = su.sid
left join employee e on e.eid = s.eid
```